# In phpDoc, is it neccessary to define parameter type?

Tags: php, phpdoc

an old fashioned example:

```
/**
 * @param string $a - test parameter
 */
public function test($a)
{
}
```

but now that Php has types, I would write:

```
/**
 * @param $a - test parameter
 */
public function test(string $a)
{
}
```

since it has a parameter, so adding "string" to phpdoc is verbose.

Answer (score 2):

"Necessary" depends on what you're using to parse the annotation (if anything)*

If this is PHPDocumentor itself, you'll want to stick with the standard that it prescribes. Even if it works without the type now, there's no guarantee that a future version will, and as mentioned in Alex Howansky's answer, the type is currently defined as mandatory. From [their manual](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/param.html#param):

> With the @param tag it is possible to document the type and function of a single argument of a function or method. **When provided it MUST contain a Type to indicate what is expected**; the description on the other hand is OPTIONAL yet RECOMMENDED in case of complicated structures, such as associative arrays.

PHPStorm (at least the version I have in front of me) acts a bit strangely if you leave out the type-hint in a parameter. If I use

```
 * @param $a Some useful comment about my parameter
```

then I get a warning about *Undefined class Some*. Apparently it's taking the first word other than the `@param` annotation and the variable name, and assuming that's the type. I can't find a reference to this behaviour in the phpdoc manual (providing the type *after* the variable), so that could itself be non-standard. Interestingly, if the first character after the variable name is a hyphen (as in the example in your question), then the warning is supressed.

I've seen a lot of code recently that leaves out the annotations entirely, and relies on the language's internal type-hinting (both parameter and return) to do the job. This is perfect, as long as you don't need to add a description to any of them. PHPStorm will warn you about missing parameter annotations the moment you provide any (but not all) of them, which means if you want to provide a comment for one then you'll need to add the rest, commented or not.

You mention verbosity in your question, and if **all** you're concerned about is human readability then by all means leave out the type. Phpdoc itself has a standard, but you're absolutely not bound by it. It's your code, ultimately. But if you're shipping a package that other developers might use, or if any of your toolchain (from IDE, through static analysis, to documentation generation itself) aren't happy with the non-standard usage, then you'll have to weigh up the decision again. Either way it comes down to whether you're the only one (person or machine) reading your code; if you're not, then stick with the standards, even if it means typing a few extra characters.

--

* This can include things that actually do affect the way the code runs - PHP allows you to fetch these annotations with the `getDocComment` methods in the [Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). Use-cases for this tend not to include `@param` annotations (more often it'll be something package specific like Doctrine's ORM annotations), which are almost exclusively used for documentation, but I don't want to over-generalise and say that this can't have an effect on your code's actual functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The [phpDocumentor docs](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html) state that the Datatype field is required for `@param`. Those docs are quite old, but I would expect apps which consume tags to still abide by that requirement. Lately, I've tended to skip the `@param` tag completely when I have an explicit typehint present.

[PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) will alert if you leave it out but have a typehint, like in your example:

```
/**
 * @param $arg The arg.
 */
public function foo(int $arg) {
```

[PHPStan](https://phpstan.org/) will alert if you have a `@param` tag type and a typehint that don't match, like this:

```
/**
 * @param string $arg The arg.
 */
public function foo(int $arg) {
```

Comment: and PhpStorm won't alert though